# How we get Previous cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am  using `SBPageFlowView` in which we get current cell. But my aim to get previous `cell`. How we get previous `cell`.

```
- (void)didReloadData:(UIView *)cell :(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[randomSearchArray count]);

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)index);
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)cell;
    NSDictionary *dict=[randomSearchArray objectAtIndex:index -1 ];
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"groupimage"]] placeholderImage:imageplaceholder];
}
```

Comment: what problem in this code?

Comment: I want to set image on default image on its previous cell

Comment: Initially set default image to each cell